# Setting values given two column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2-time series data frames. Both contain values [0,1] only. The first one is called `init_signal` and the second is called `end_signal`. The idea is to create a new data frame when `init_signal` has a `1`, it will find the NEXT 1 in `end_signal`.

The example below merges both the init_signal and end_signal as one data frame. the first column is init_signal and the second column is end_signal.

For example:

```
2016-06-13  1  0
2016-06-14  0  0
2016-06-15  0  1
2016-06-16  0  0
```

Will become:

```
2016-06-13  1  
2016-06-14  1  
2016-06-15  1  
2016-06-16  0
```

For example 2:

```
2016-06-13  1  1
2016-06-14  0  0
2016-06-15  0  1
2016-06-16  0  0
```

Will become:

```
2016-06-13  1  
2016-06-14  1  
2016-06-15  1  
2016-06-16  0
```

In the 2nd example, if there is also a 1 in the same row as the init_signal, it will be ignored.

I've been using a complex loop. Is there a non-looping way?

Comment: If this is about pandas, please tag it as such.

Comment: A (single) loop is just an syntactic element to express a O(n) complexity. So now Imagine how to determine all values without viewing every value at least once? It's not possible. In either init_signal status (0 or 1) you have to find either the next init_signal = 1 or the next end_signal = 1 and therefore you have to visit each line once. You can only determine the column you have to look at in the current iteration.

Comment: Is a pandas data frame the best tool for the problem you're trying to solve? Depending on the context and constraints: the issue is may be solvable with substantially less complexity given a different model for persisting your init and end signals.

Comment: You've said that occurrences where `end_signal == 1` should be ignored unless they come after an occurrence of `init_signal == 1`. What should the result be if there is a second `init_signal == 1` before an `end_signal == 1` is found?

Comment: Can you post the code you already have to help us understand what logic you trying to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps and covers all the boundary conditions.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# Dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['init_signal'] = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
df['end_signal']  = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
df.index = [dt.date.today()+dt.timedelta(-i) for i in reversed(range(len(df)))]

# Cumsum for calculation
df['init_c'] = df['init_signal'].cumsum()
df['end_c']  = df['end_signal'].cumsum()

# result calculation
func = lambda x: (x==x.min()).shift().fillna(True)
df['result'] = df.groupby('init_c')['end_c'].transform(func)
df['result'] = df['result']&df['init_c'].astype(bool)
df['result'] = df['result'].astype(int)

# dropping temp columns
df.drop(['init_c','end_c'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
            init_signal  end_signal  result
2018-12-12            0           0       0
2018-12-13            0           1       0
2018-12-14            0           0       0
2018-12-15            1           0       1
2018-12-16            0           0       1
2018-12-17            0           0       1
2018-12-18            0           1       1
2018-12-19            0           0       0
2018-12-20            1           1       1
2018-12-21            0           0       1
2018-12-22            0           0       1
2018-12-23            0           1       1
2018-12-24            0           0       0
2018-12-25            0           1       0
2018-12-26            0           0       0
2018-12-27            0           0       0
2018-12-28            1           0       1
2018-12-29            0           1       1
2018-12-30            0           0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
df1 = df.assign(end_signal = df['end_signal'].where(df['init_signal'].values != 1, 0))
df1 = df1.set_index('time')
(df1['init_signal'] + df1['end_signal'].shift().bfill()*-1).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
         time    0
0  2016-06-13  1.0
1  2016-06-14  1.0
2  2016-06-15  1.0
3  2016-06-16  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This can achieved in three steps and 0 loops:

1. Create a single column with the `init_signal` and `end_signal`.
   (Records with both default to start signal only.)
2. Fill the dates with
   no activity.
3. Add the end signal back as active.

Note: I'm not sure how to handle cases at the beginning. I'm presuming that there will *always* be an `init_signal` preceding an `end_signal`. If that's not true, you'll need to build a handler for that, but that would be a simple conditional at the end of these steps.

### Step 1: A single columns

In this step we create a column that has only days where there was a `init_signal` and `end_signal`.

```
 import numpy as np
 df['result'] = np.nan
 #Add end dates
 mask = (df['end_signal'] == 1)
 df.loc[mask,'result'] = 0
 #Add init_signals.
 #Note: This will overwrite days that already have an end_signal
 mask = (df['init_signal'] == 1)
 df.loc[mask,'result'] = 1
```

### Step 2: Fill the columns

This will take the na values and replace them with the status that occurred most recently.

```
 df.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

### Step 3: Set end_signal to active.

In definitions, we said that dates with an `end_signal` should be 1, so we need to add that back to the dataframe.

```
 mask = (df['end_signal'] == 1)
 df.loc[mask,'result'] = 1
```

Comment: Saw some other answers that look simpler. though this is three steps, each step is vectorised so it should be faster. Might want to run and compare with your data.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a non-looping way to incorporate the logic you want (and if there is, it isn't simpler than a loop). See below...

```
df['status'] = 0
for i in df.index:
    if df.xs(i)['init_signal'] == 1:
        df.at[i,'status'] = 1
    elif i != 0 and df.xs(i-1)['status'] == 1 and df.xs(i)['end_signal'] != 1:
        df.at[i,'status'] = 1
    else:
        df.at[i,'status'] = 0
```

This creates a 'status' column that will be zero until init_signal is turned 'on' and will remain 'on' until end_signal = 1 on a day where the init_signal is also not equal to 1 (per your example 2). Other non-looping solutions seem to run into trouble when multiple end/init signals are given in a row.